# Windows login dialog (Capture login and Pass) Windows, .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, impersonation

I am working on application which needs to be authenticated in different domain. To authenticate a user I have to capture his/her credentials send to server side and enter them into LsaUserLogon() function to impersonate user.

My fear here is, what I don't want take responsibility for Pop up my own dialog, /cript/encript information for transmittion. I am looking for different approach which removes all responsibility for me to capture user passwords. Only fact here, what I need this credentials on my server machine, to impersonate user. Any tips and suggestions?

( Windows, .NET )

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has native API to assist in this case (which helps you launch an IE style dialog to prompt for user name and password).

You can invoke it in .NET,

http://www.microsoft.com/indonesia/msdn/credmgmt.aspx